# In RabbitMQ why exchange accepts messages on second run?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, amqp

So the situation is.

I'm working with PHP PECL AMQP RabbitMQ client. When I'm trying to send a message to exchange for the first time, nothing happens. It seems that the message haven't been sent, and AMQPQueue::get returns nothing, even though AMQPExchange::publish returns true.

After that (i.e. after second exchange declaration) everything works fine.

What can it be?

**UPD. Code sample.**

```
<?php
$connection = new AMQPConnection;
//config...
$connection->connect();

$channel = new AMQPChannel($connection);

$exchange = new AMQPExchange($channel);
$exchange->setName('test_exchange');
$exchange->setType(AMQP_EX_TYPE_DIRECT);
$exchange->declareExchange();
$exchange->setFlags(AMQP_DURABLE);

$exchange->bind('test_exchange', 'test_routing_key');
$exchange->publish('test_message', 'test_routing_key');

$queue = new AMQPQueue($channel);
$queue->setName('test_routing_key');
$queue->declareQueue();
$queue->bind('test_exchange', 'test_routing_key');
var_dump($queue->get(AMQP_AUTOACK));
```

Comment: can you paste the code

Comment: can you paste the code

Comment: There you go, sample code.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between publishing and routing:
Publishing means sending a message **to** an exchange, whereas routing means sending the message **from** an exchange to a bound entity (e.g. a queue or another exchange).

Your first message is published, but not routed since no queue is bound to the exchange with the matching routing key at that time. AMQPExchange::publish returning true just confirms, that the exchange received the message.

See [this picture](http://www.rabbitmq.com/img/tutorials/intro/hello-world-example-routing.png) taken from the [RabbitMQ - AMQP 0-9-1 Model Explained](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html) section.

If you definetly need to know if a message was routed to at least one queue, you can set the mandatory flag: ([RabbitMQ - Reliability Guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/reliability.html))

> If messages may be routed in more complex ways but the producer still needs to know if they reached at least one queue, it can set the mandatory flag on a basic.publish, ensuring that a basic.return (containing a reply code and some textual explanation) will be sent back to the client if no queues were appropriately bound.

Comment: Makes sense. I'll check.